# Automatic Multiple plot function in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have two sets of time series variables.

```
WSN = c(HMn25_29,HMn28_29,HMn29_29)
Ref = c(suplmentryfor29,suplmentryob29)
```

I wanted to have plots that presents an elements of WSN set with an element of Ref.
In other words, I want to visualize {HMn25_29,suplmentryfor29},{HMn28_29,suplmentryfor29},{HMn28_29,suplmentryfor29},{HMn25_29,suplmentryob29},{HMn25_29,suplmentryob29},{HMn25_29,suplmentryob29}.

Expected results:

[image]

sample Data for WSN:

```
                    dt   temp
1 2007-09-29 00:00:00 -1.874500
2 2007-09-29 01:00:00 -1.693667
3 2007-09-29 02:00:00 -1.766667
4 2007-09-29 03:00:00 -1.928667
5 2007-09-29 04:00:00 -2.132581
6 2007-09-29 05:00:00 -1.752258
```

Sample for Ref data:

```
           HMn29_29.h   V1
1 2007-09-29 00:00:00 -1.8
2 2007-09-29 01:00:00 -1.9
3 2007-09-29 02:00:00 -2.4
4 2007-09-29 03:00:00 -2.3
5 2007-09-29 04:00:00 -2.3
6 2007-09-29 05:00:00 -2.4
```

Moreover, I have the code to plot the individually. 
The code that plot variables individually:

```
plot29 <- list(HMn25_29,HMn28_29,HMn29_29,HMn31_29,HMn32_29,suplmentryfor29,suplmentryob29)
Mainn <- c('Node 25','Node 28','Node 29','Node 31','Node 32', 'MetoSwiss Forecast Grid Point', "MetoSwiss Sensing Station")
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
for (i in seq_along(plot29))  {
  plot(plot29[[i]], type = "o", pch = 16, lty = 2, col = "Black", xlab = "Hour  (2007/09/29)" , ylab = "Ambient Tempreture")
  title(Mainn[[i]])
}
```

Now, I need a automatic function that get the list and present the plots with aforementioned properties two by two where x-axis illustrates time-date and y-axis present absolute values of variables in a same scale, let's say -2 ~ 10. Moreover, each plot should include legend.

Comment: -1 : I see I am not the only person who has developed an allergy toward repeated postings that do not present data objects in a reproducible manner.

Comment: Open an empty plot with appropriate `xlim` and `ylim` args, then Just put `lines()` in the loop instead of opening a whole new plot window in each iteration- you can then iterate over vectors of `col` and `lty` args for the lines themselves.

Comment: @DWin, I put the data sample and minimum runable code that I had.

Answer (score 0):

The ts.plot and plot.ts functions in R both allow you to plot multiple lines to a plot, maybe you could try that?  Here's a simple example:

```
a<-c(1:5)
b<-c(2:6)
ts.plot(cbind(a,b))
```

An alternative is to use "par(new=TRUE)" before you make new graphs, which tells R to put the new graph in the device you used last time, without clearing the old graph.  This isn't neat, but it may give you more flexibility.  If you decide to go this rout, you'll want to plot omit the axes and labels for the later plots, and set xlim and ylim manually, or else they will look off.